# How to make Excel save a file as text, with support for Unicode, and support for multiple lines within a cell (alt-enter)?

Tags: excel, unicode, text-files

My application needs to pass data back and forth via text files with Excel.  My text files will have Unicode text, and will also need to have some way of indicating mulitple lines within a cell (which I believe is the LF character (ascii 10)).

Excel can read my csv file correctly.  However, when I save the csv file in Excel, it replaces the Unicode characters with ?'s.  So although it still looks fine in Excel, if I close Excel and re-open the file with Excel, I see ?'s instead of my Unicode characters.

If instead of Excel saving as csv, I save as Unicode text, that produces a tab-delimited file that does have the Unicode characters.  However, if I close the file and re-open it with Excel, it takes me through an import wizard that does not recognize the LF character (produced by alt-enter) to indicate a new line within a cell.  Instead, it treats the LF as a new row.

How can I get Excel to save in a text format that supports both Unicode and multiple lines within a cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get around this problem do not open the .txt file from Excel.  Instead right click on the file in file explorer and choose open with Excel.

If you save the .txt file with .xls extension you can double click on the file in file explorer to open in Excel.

**To Open From Excel**

- Click File/Open...
- Select the .txt file to open.
- Hold down the Shift key when clicking on the Open button.

Comment: in Windows Explorer, how do I add Excel to my Open With menu?  It is not listed in either Recommended Programs or Other Programs, and I can't find it when I browse.  Where is it?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2003 and for me it located here:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\Excel.exe

Comment: this works! I guess I have to instruct my users to do it this way. FYI for anyone else with this problem: the file needs to be in Unicode 16 (FFFE little endian or FEFF big endian).  Any way to get Excel to do this when you double-click on the file in Explorer? How about when you open Excel and select this file from the recent files list? Or in Excel, open and browse to this file?

Comment: Found a way you can double click on the file to open in Excel (See Edit).  Still no idea how to do it from File/Open...

Comment: Ok also found a way to open from Excel (See Edit).  Excel has some strange hidden features.

Comment: @Grzegorz I put my results in the edit section of the answer. :)

Comment: excellent!  That is good to know!  Any idea about getting it to work from Excel's recently used list?

Comment: awesome. do you remember how you found about this workaround Mr. Persichetti?

Comment: @David.  Sorry I couldn't find a way to do it from the recently used list.
@Eric.  The right click open with... Excel is something I've always used.  I didn't know it didn't work from Excel until I read this question.  As for holding down the shift key, just something I decided to try to see what would happened.  Thought of the shift key because I know if you hold down the shift key when clicking on the Edit menu item the Copy menu item changes to Copy Picture...