# how to make opening txt file in Excel work like if you right-click in Windows Explorer and Open With Excel?

Tags: excel, unicode, windows-explorer, text-files

My application interfaces with Excel using tab-delimited Unicode text files.  I require that some cells have multiple lines (alt-enter in Excel, produces LF character (10)).

If I right-click on the txt file in Explorer and Open With..Excel, it opens correctly.  However, if I open Excel, and from within Excel either open the txt file by browsing to it, or open it through the Most Recently Used list, it treats the LF as a CR and creates a new row starting at that point.

How can I get Excel to open the file correctly from within Excel (i.e., open the file the same way as if I had right-clicked on it in Explorer and selected Open With..Excel)?

Edit:  Chris Persichetti provided a lot of good information on a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389796/how-to-make-excel-save-a-file-as-text-with-support-for-unicode-and-support-for).

Comment: more of a superuser question? Anyways, the 'open with excel' just passes the text file as a command line parameter.

Comment: any idea why it works differently from within Excel?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should try this: on the ribbon, click the Data tab, then in the "Get External Data" section, click "From Text". this allows you to customize how excel opens the text file.

Comment: Thaks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that brings up the Text Import Wizard, which does not know how to deal with line feeds in a cell.  At this point, we've shipped out product with warnings to read the help file, so hopefully our users will avoid this issue.